# SocketTimeoutException problem - how to continue after exception

Tags: java

I write and read in my function using Socket class. I used

```
synchronized(socket){
.//write;
//read;
}
```

I am doing this (repeat) every 50-1000 ms. Problem is when somebody ( unknown reason ) pluged off  cable ( I got SocketTimeoutException). When he pluged in again, I need to continue.
What to do ? Do I need to close this socket in catch block and create new ? Or something else ?

Comment: `SocketTimeoutException` is a fatal exception, if you have to continue you need a new connection and possibly persisted state of what has been done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. Just continue. If you get any *other* exception, close the Socket and restart (if appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a Decorator implementation that was willing to catch a SocketTimeoutException and retry. It could retry a certain number of times, over a certain interval before actually passing the exception along to indicate a "true" (to be defined) error condition. It could even retry indefinitely if you want. The retry logic may even encapsulate re-establishing the socket, though a timeout isn't enough to require that.

Another option is the CircuitBreaker Pattern, though it's not quite designed for what you are describing. CircuitBreaker is a bit better for avoiding costly errors that may be occurring over a period of time.